# Compact set which isn't convex hull of its extreme points

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Consider $\ell^\infty$. Let

$$A := \overline{\operatorname{conv}}\left(\left\{\dfrac{e_n}{n}\right\}\right)$$

It's not hard to see that this set is compact (using the [Banach-Alaoglu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem) theorem). But how can we show that $A \ne \operatorname{conv}(\operatorname{ex}(A))$?

The only way I see it is to find some convex combination of some points $\{a_i\} \in \operatorname{conv}(\operatorname{ex}(A)) \notin A$. Any hints, please?

Comment: You need to find a point in $A$ that is not a convex combination of the extreme points, if possible. Which topology are you using? the strong or the weak*? The reference to Alaoglu suggests it is the latter, but you should make it clear. Then, try to identify the extreme points.

Comment: @Yuval, the norm closure of $\text{conv}\{e_n/n\}$ is compact, so all other standard topologies agree there.

Comment: @Ruy Indeed, you are right.

Comment: Openspace, notice that $A$ is convex, so 
$\operatorname{conv}(\operatorname{ex}(A)) \subseteq A$.  So you need to find some element in $A$ that is not in the convex hull!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $0 \in A$, so every finitely supported vector $x=(x_k)_{k \ge 1}$ with nonnegative entries such that $s(x)=\sum_{k \ge 1} kx_k \le 1$ is in $A$. Indeed,
$$x=\sum_k  {kx_k}\cdot(e_k/k)+(1-s(x))\cdot 0 \,.$$

Passing to the limit, we deduce that
$$A=\{x=(x_k)_{k \ge 1}: \forall k\ge 1  \; \;   x_k \ge 0 \; \:\text{and} \; \; \sum_{k \ge 1} kx_k \le 1\}\,.$$
Thus the extreme points of $A$ are $0$ and $e_k/k$ for $k \ge 1$, since if
$x \in A$ has $x_k x_\ell>0$ where $k\ne \ell$, then for positive $\epsilon<\min\{k x_k,\ell x_\ell\}$, the vectors

$$y=x+(\epsilon/k)e_k-(\epsilon/\ell) e_\ell \in A$$
and
$$z=x-(\epsilon/k)e_k+(\epsilon/\ell) e_\ell \in A$$
satisfy $x=(y+z)/2$.
Finally,
$$\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{e_k}{k^2(k+1)} \in A$$ is not a finite convex combination
of $0$ and $e_k/k$ for $k \ge 1$.

Comment: I'm not sure about extreme points idea. If we consider arifmetic mean of $x_1$ and $x_2$ it will have $\tilde{x}_k = x_k + \frac{\epsilon}{2k}$ and $\tilde{x}_{l} = x_l -\frac{\epsilon}{2l}$.

Comment: @openspace   It seems the words I used were confusing, so I replaced them by formulas. Is it clearer now?